# How do I change a pointers value in a function in C

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-value

the code is:

```
     int main(int argc, const char* argv[] )
     {
        struct node * initialpointer=NULL;
        insert("asd", initialpointer, 1);
        if(initialpointer!=NULL)
            printf("isnotnull");
        if (initialpointer==NULL)
            printf("isnull");
     }
     insert(char* x,struct node * initialpointer, int numberofelements){
        struct node B;
        B.word = x;
        B.parent = NULL;
        B.leftchild = NULL;
        B.rightchild = NULL;
        printf("%d", 12);
        if ( initialpointer == NULL){
           initialpointer = &B;
           B.parent = NULL;
        }
     }
```

So in the end I want `initialpointer` to point where nde B is but in the main method it prints it is null. So how can I change the `initialpointer` in function insert permanently?

Comment: `B` is deleted when the function exits. you should allocate memory (`malloc`) for your `initialpointer` node.

Comment: Can you trim out all the irrelevant bits of your code? The `numberofelements` value seems to be irrelevant to the problem, for example, as does anything to do with the `parent`/`leftchild`/`rightchild` values.

Comment: the methods are langer than they seem. I cut off the irrelevant parts already. but I did not want to change the structure of the functions and function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your code.

First is the problem you're having. The pointer you're passing to `insert` is passed by copy; the function gets a copy and `main` doesn't see your change. The solution to this is to pass a pointer to the pointer. See the POSIX function `strtol` for a standard library example of how this looks.

The second problem is that you're returning a pointer to a local, automatic (i.e. stack-allocated) variable. Since the stack is released on function exit, this pointer points to invalid memory when it is back in `main`. So instead you need to allocate `B` from the heap.

So, fixing things up:

```
 int main(int argc, const char* argv[] )
 {
    struct node * initialpointer=NULL;
    insert("asd", &initialpointer, 1);
    if(initialpointer!=NULL)
        printf("isnotnull");
    if (initialpointer==NULL)
        printf("isnull");
 }
 insert(char* x,struct node ** initialpointer, int numberofelements){
    struct node *B;
    B = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    B->word = x;
    B->parent = NULL;
    B->leftchild = NULL;
    B->rightchild = NULL;
    printf("%d", 12);
    if ( *initialpointer == NULL){
       *initialpointer = B;
       B->parent = NULL;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you it seems like working. Can you give some more information about the idea. Why am I passing the address of initialpointer?

Comment: Because, when you call a function, the function only ever gets a *copy* of what you pass it. Pass an integer? The function gets a copy, and can alter it however it wants and the calling code sees nothing. Pass a pointer? Same thing; function gets a copy. So in this case, you pass a pointer to the pointer (i.e. a `struct node **`). The copy passed to the function then points to the original `struct node *`, and the function can alter it. The general guideline is: *If the function needs to alter it, you need to pass a pointer to it.*

Answer (score 4):

Do not return a pointer to a local variable, this will result in a dangling pointer:

```
struct node B;
...
initialpointer = &B;
```

You need to pass a pointer to a pointer to a `struct node` to `insert()` and `malloc()` a new `struct node` inside `insert()`:

```
insert(char* x,struct node ** initialpointer, int numberofelements)
{
    if (NULL == *initialpointer)
    {
        *initialpointer = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (*initialpointer)
        {
            /* Note: you should probably make a copy of 'x',
               using 'strdup()' or similar, otherwise there
               is requiremenet that 'x' exist for the lifetime
               of '*initialpointer': which would be error prone. */
            (*initialpointer)->word       = x;
            (*initialpointer)->parent     = NULL;
            (*initialpointer)->leftchild  = NULL;
            (*initialpointer)->rightchild = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

This retains the logic of the original `insert()` as a `node` should only be created and assigned to `initialpointer` if `initialpointer` is `NULL`.

And invoke it:

```
struct node * initialpointer=NULL;
insert("asd", &initialpointer, 1);
```

Remembering to `free()` it when no longer required:

```
free(initialpointer);
```

Comment: number of elements is ignored though. but maybe he doesn't need it.

Comment: @vulkanino, yes. The OP may just be working his way towards using that and is wanting to ensure he can return a new node.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node * initialpointer=NULL;
insert("asd", &initialpointer, 1);
...
void insert(char* x,struct node ** initialpointer, int numberofelements){
...
if ( *initialpointer == NULL){
    *initialpointer = &B;
```

But keep in mind that this as well won't work with your current `B` as auto (local) variable.

You must `malloc()` `B`.

And you are missing an `else` branch in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Edited per @Paul Mitchell's comment.

```
 int main(int argc, const char* argv[] )
 {
    struct node* initialpointer = insert("asd");
    if ( initialpointer == NULL )
       /* handle the error */

    /* remember to free() all the allocated nodes */
 }


 struct node* insert(char* x)
 {
    struct node* initialpointer = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if ( initialpointer == NULL)
        return NULL;  

    initialpointer.word = x;
    initialpointer.parent = NULL;
    initialpointer.leftchild = NULL;
    initialpointer.rightchild = NULL;
    return initialpointer;
 }
```

This will allocate a **single** node (I've removed the `numberofelements` parameter).

To allocate space for more than a node, you have to pass a pointer to a pointer. But if I understand your intent, you want a node to be part of a linked structure, maybe a tree, so you don't need to create a container for the nodes, since you can traverse the structure to access the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic for two reasons.

First of all, you are changing a local-scope variable, since `initialpointer` is a parameter of your function. That means, regardless of its type, what you write to the variable itself is only visible inside your `insert` function. If you were writing to `*initialpointer` that would be whole different story.

Now, what is even more problematic is that `B` is a local variable that is sitting on the stack inside your function. Once that function is left, the storage location of `B` will be invalid. Hence, if you return the pointer to `B`, accessing that object outside of `insert` will invoke *undefined behaviour* and will very likely not work (you have a slim chance that that particular location has not been altered, but that is pure luck).

What you probably want instead of

```
initialpointer = &B;
```

is this:

```
*initialpointer = B;
```

This will copy the `B` object to the storage location that is referenced by the pointer variable. Now it is okay for `B` to go out of scope, because you copied everything to the `initialpointer` variable that is sitting inside **main**.

Note that the `initialpointer` variable inside `main` is a completely different thing than the one in `insert`!

---

One last thing, giving variables names that start with uppercase letters is not valid in *any* naming scheme I came across so far.

Comment: That wont work. You say that put B into where initial pointer points. However it usually points critical parts in memory and When i do that i get segmantation fault

Comment: Yes, that is correct. At some point you have to allocate some memory for it. This can be done either on stack of `main` (by declaring an actual `struct node` variable -- not a pointer) or dynamically by calling `malloc`. Once you have a valid place to put your data, you can write to it inside your `insert` function.